# Python Thread.start blocking in a subprocess?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, subprocess

I have a Python class which starts a `subprocess` that runs another Python program; the first thing it does is spwans a`threading.Thread` to do some other other work. However, regardless of what the thread's `target` is, the `Thread.start` call is blocking, and the rest of the program is not executed.

What could possibly be causing this problem? Is it some general problem regarding the Python global interpreter lock?

EDIT:For some more background, it's a subprocess that runs a single PyTest unit test; inside the unit test, a thread is being started to create a server (the server creation isn't a problem, the `threading.Thread.start` problem occurs regardless).

The subprocess call is

```
subprocess.Popen(['/usr/local/bin/py.test', '-v', test_path, '-k', 
                               test_name],
                               cwd=grading_path,
                               env=env,
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                               stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

stdout, stderr = result.communicate()
```

and the threading call is

```
def test_case_1(self):
    t = Thread(target=time.sleep, args=(1,)) # fake target, doesn't work regardless
    t.start() # it blocks here

    ... other logic ....
```

There is communication between the subprocess and the and the parent process; the subprocess basically just sends back some result data.

Comment: Can you show us your code for starting the subprocess and the code for setting up and running the thread? Are you doing any IO in the parent process? Are you doing any IPC between the processes?

Comment: @TomDalton added a bit more detail

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, specifically please give us enough code/info to reproduce the problem. It seems like your issue has to do with some kind of deadlock, but as it stands your question reads "please help me find which part of my code (not shared) is causing deadlock".

Comment: Can you show us the code the parent uses to receive data from the child, in relation to starting the subpocess?

Comment: How do you know that `t.start()` blocks? I don't see what how `subprocess` module is related to your issue. Are you suggesting that if you run `py.test` from the command-line manually then the code stops blocking?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yup, if I run the test by itself, it works fine. However, when it's started from the subprocess it blocks there. I added debug statements to see that code before the `t.start()` is executed, but code after isn't.